# Eclipse RCP which shell to use for popups

Tags: java, popup, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to get hold of a shell in Eclipse RCP and bring up popups in my application and had gone through several resources/tutorials to achieve the task but without much luck.

### Tried:

```
Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
```

or

```
Display.getDefault().getActiveShell();
```

or

```
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
```

or sometimes even

```
 Display.getDefault().getShells()[0];
```

But different things seem to work in different situations.

Resources online have different views and most things I find say you shouldn't really use the `Display` class at all but I am trying to bring up a popup from within an eclipse Job. It's got to the end and failed and the popup needs to be displayed using:

### Code:

```
        Display.getCurrent().syncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                    MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Publish", e.getMessage());


            }
        });
    }
```

The popup is inside a Runnable being executed from a Thread started from an Eclipse Job. It's complex but necessary to provide progress bar updates whilst calling a synchronous method on a server.

It doesn't work and I don't know why. Just getting a null from the getActiveShell() call.

The real question though isn't 'why doesn't my code work' but was is the definitively correct way to get a shell for a popup in Eclipse RCP framework, and especial in situations where you can't access a workbench?

Answer (score 13):

Looking though the Eclipse source there does not seem to be a definitive way. The closest is some variant of

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
```

Even if this returns `null` that is still acceptable to `MessageDialog`.

`DebugUIPlugin` has this more elaborate version:

```
public static Shell getShell() {
  IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
  if (window == null) {
    IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
    if (windows.length > 0) {
       return windows[0].getShell();
    }
  }
  else {
    return window.getShell();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Use of `MessageDialog` from a `Job` is rare in the Eclipse source. As the Job runs asynchronously a popup from the Job could be rather unexpected.

In Eclipse 4 applications if you can get the `IEclipseContext` there should be an `IShellProvider` in the context. e4 apps can also use `StatusReporter` which does not need a shell.

In e4 applications you can also inject the active shell using:

```java
@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell
```

Comment: how could one get the `IShellProvider` from the Eclipse context?

Comment: @Campa You can inject it or use IEclipseContext.get (this is for e4 applications only).